# From 'list of lists of lists' to 'list of lists' - Python

Tags: python, list, flatten

I have an issue I cannot go thorugh. I need list of lists instead of list of lists of lists? Is there any simple command that 'unlists' one level of such 'deep' list in Python? Here is what I have:

```
[[['this', 'is', 'the', 'good', 'machine', 'learning', 'book']],
[['this', 'is', 'another', 'book']]]
```

and where I need to get to:

```
[['this', 'is', 'the', 'good', 'machine', 'learning', 'book'],
['this', 'is',  'another', 'book']]
```

I was trying to resolve it with function below

```
from pandas.core.common import flatten
list(flatten(x))
```

...but it breaks everything into one list...

```
['this', 'is', 'the', 'good', 'machine', 'learning', 'book', 'this', 'is',  'another', 'book']
```

Pls help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply apply it only to the sublists:

```
[list(flatten(y)) for y in x]
```

Comment: Wow, so easy... :) Thank you, it works! I'm switching from R to Python and some things suprise me in Python...

Answer (score 1):

```
[item for sub_list in your_list for item in sub_list]
```

Comment: I stay with flatten from Pandas but this one also works. Thak you!